# Concatenating the first character of first name and the last name in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Question: New to Oracle SQL and cant figure this out. Any Help is appreciated. :)

In table employee2, generate the email address for column **username** for each student by
concatenating the first character of employee’s first name and the employee’s last name. For
instance, the username of employee Peter Stone will be pstone. NOTE: the username is in all
lower case letters.

What I have Tried:

```
select 
  concat(left(firstname, 1) + ' ',left(lastname)) UserName
from employee2;
```

select
concat(substring(firstname, 1),substring(lastname)) UserName
from employee2;

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Mureinik the above code gives me error, as stated above i need to write a query that concatenates the first character of firstname with the lastname and adds it to the column named "username" in the employee2 table.

Comment: Care to share the error?

Comment: ORA-00904: "LEFT": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 94 Column: 35
@Mureinik

Answer (score 2):

You should use `substr` and concatanation operator `||` as follows:

```
Update employee2
   Set username = lower(substr(firstname,1,1) || lastname)
```

Benifit of using `||` over `concat` function is that `concat` need to be called multiple times if there are more than two strings need to be combined. `||` is string operator and easy to use and read.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here:

1. Oracle doesn't have a `left` function - but you could use `substr` to generate that effect.
2. Strings in Oracle are concatenated by the `||` operator, not `+`
3. You should convert the username to lowercase:

```sql
SELECT TOLOWER(SUBSTR(firstname, 1, 1) || lastname) AS username
FROM   employee2
```

Comment: ORA-00904: "TO_LOWER": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 93 Column: 8

getting this error also the username column already exist its just empty need to fill it with the first + last name criteria

Comment: @CuzWhyNotVlogs arg, sorry, that was supposed to be `lower`, not `tolower`. Edited and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
select (substr(firstname, 1,1) || lower(lastname)) as UserName 
 from employee2;
```

Comment: how would i insert this data into the field username that already exist and is empty in the employee2 table

Comment: @CuzWhyNotVlogs Use merge clause to update existing rows and insert when not matched

Comment: How would you write the above query then?

Answer (score 0):

```
select lower(concat(substr(firstname,1,1),lastname)) Username from employee2;

or 

select lower(substr(firstname,1,1)||lastname)  from employee2;

Insert with select

SQL> create table test (id number,uname varchar2(100));

SQL> insert into test
  2  select rownum,lower(concat(substr(first_name,1,1),last_name))||'@gmail.com'
  3  from employees;

108 rows created.


SQL> commit;

Commit complete.


SQL> select * from test
  2  fetch first 5 rows only;

        ID UNAME
---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 eabel@gmail.com
         2 sande@gmail.com
         3 matkinson@gmail.com
         4 daustin@gmail.com
         5 hbaer@gmail.com


SQL>
```

Comment: I am trying to insert this data instead of just selecting it. How would this query change then? @Sam

Answer (score 0):

```
MERGE INTO employee 2 
USING (select (substr(firstname, 1,1) || lower(lastname)) as UserName 
 from employee 1) ilv;
ON ilv.username = 2.username
   
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (username)
        values(ilv.username);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE employee2
SET username = lower(CONCAT(substr(firstname, 1,1),lastname));
```

Thanks everyone for your help, might have not explained my question correctly but this is the output i wanted to achieve.